# Is there a way to sync the search query between Visual Studio Code's "Find" and "Find in Workspace" functionality?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to configure VSCode so that:

- When I search for a string using VSCode's "Find" functionality:
  [image: Using "Find" to search for "some string"]
- And I open the "Find in Workspace" view:
  [image: "Find in Workspace" view]

Expected behavior:

- The string I searched for with the "Find" functionality automatically gets filled in the "Search" form field above.

Actual behavior:

- the "Search" form field appears empty.

And vice versa: when I search with "Find in Workspace", the "Find" functionality gets filled automatically.

Does anybody know how to accomplish that? Thanks!